# Find Day of Week Without Using Calendar function in Java

Tags: java, calendar

I need to find the day of the week (i.e. Monday, Tuesday...) given MM-DD-YYYY. So basically what java calendar would do, but without using java calendar.

Comment: That's an odd thing to need, why do you need it and what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Then you need to determine the day-of-year and whether a year is a leapyear, Then modulo 7 (`% 7`) you can compare it with a known weekday & date, for instance today.

Comment: Is this homework for a programming class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, though unusual, to compute a number that corresponds to the day of the week from a calendar date.

In brief, you will first need to calculate a serial date number from the calendar date, i.e. a number that is a continuous count of days that have elapsed since a certain fixed point in time (informally called 'the epoch').  The most commonly encountered serial date scheme encountered in modern computing is Posix Time, which has an epoch date of Jan 1, 1970 at midnight UTC.

You will need to decide what level of precision is needed for this calculation, eg. whether you will need to account for the Julian Calendar (used in most of Europe before the Gregorian Calendar reform by Pope Gregory in 1584), whether to correct for century days, etc.

Several algorithms are available to arithmetically convert a calendar date to a serial date number with a given epoch. Historically, the most commonly used epoch for these calculations has been the Julian Day number system (not to be confused with the Julian Calendar), which counts days from November 24, 4714 BC in the proleptic Gregorian calendar.  Below is Java code which implements one such algorithm published by Jean Meeus in his book "Astronomical Algorithms, 2nd Ed."  This algorithm computes a Julian Day number and assumes that days are exactly 86400 seconds in length, accounts for the general Gregorian Reform, and accounts for century and leap days:

```
public class JulianDay {

    private static final int YEAR = 0;
    private static final int MONTH = 1;
    private static final int DAY = 2;
    private static final int HOURS = 3;
    private static final int MINUTES = 4;
    private static final int SECONDS = 5;
    private static final int MILLIS = 6;

    :
    :

    // Converts a timestamp presented as an array of integers in the following
    // order (from index 0 to 6): year,month,day,hours,minutes,seconds,millis
    // month (1-12), day (1-28 or 29), hours (0-23), min/sec (0-59) to a
    // Julian Day Number.
    // For clarity and simplicity, the input values are assumed to be well-formed;
    // error checking is not implemented in the snippet.

    public static double toJD(int[] ymd_hms) {

        int y = ymd_hms[YEAR];
        int m = ymd_hms[MONTH];
        double d = (double) ymd_hms[DAY];

        d = d + ((ymd_hms[HOURS] / 24.0) +
                 (ymd_hms[MINUTES] / 1440.0) +
                 (ymd_hms[SECONDS] / 86400.0) +
                 (ymd_hms[MILLIS] / 86400000.0));

        if (m == 1 || m == 2) {
            y--;
            m = m + 12;
        }

        double a = Math.floor(y / 100);
        double b = 2 - a + Math.floor(a / 4);

        return (Math.floor(365.25 * (y + 4716.0)) +
               Math.floor(30.6001 * (m + 1)) +
               d + b - 1524.5);
    }
}
```

Once you have a serial date number, it is straightforward to compute the day of the week from the remainder when the date number is divided by 7 (the number of days in a week).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about simply avoiding the Calendar Object then you could use the Date Object (deprecated) but still works and call setMonth, setYear, and setDate to get the desired date. You then have to use a DateFormatter to get your desired output. I used a SimpleDateFormat and the E specifier to get the day of the week.

```
  Date dNow = new Date();
  SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("E");

  System.out.println("Current Date: " + ft.format(dNow));
```

This outputs the current day of the week "Sun", "Sat", etc..
This link will help with the formatting https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Using the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old date-time classes. The `LocalDate` class represents a date without a time-of-day and without a time zone.

```
DayOfWeek dow =
    LocalDate.parse( 
        "01-23-2016" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uuuu" )
    ).getDayOfWeek()
```

That code returns a [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum object. From there you can interrogate for:

- Integer number, 1-7 for Monday-Sunday
- Localized name of the day.

Example code.

```
int dowNumber = dow.getValue() ;
String dowName = dow.getDisplayName( 
    TextStyle.FULL , 
    Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;  // Or Locale.US, Locale.ITALY, etc.
```

**TIP:** Pass around the `DayOfWeek` objects themselves in your own code, rather than internally track the day-of-week as a number or string. This makes your code more self-documenting, ensures valid values, and provides for [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer myself and found another answer based on [Zeller's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence):

```
// d = day in month
// m = month (January = 1 : December = 12)
// y = 4 digit year
// Returns 0 = Sunday .. 6 = Saturday
public int dow(int d, int m, int y) {
  if (m < 3) {
    m += 12;
    y--;
  }
  return (d + int((m+1)*2.6) +  y + int(y/4) + 6*int(y/100) + int(y/400) + 6) % 7;
}
```

Source: [here](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/3350/getting-the-day-of-the-week-without-calendar)